# How to create custom slider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to create custom slider like this?

[image: Slider]

i don't see function (interval and stepSize) in Slider() and CupertinoSlider()

Comment: customPaint with GeustureDetector may work fine in this case.

Comment: can you explain it ? can i using Slider() and CupertinoSlider() ? or i must custom using GestureDetector ? @YeasinSheikh